# Filter By Content Type using xm edge GraphQL endpoint

Tags: graphql, experience-edge

I am trying to use the search query to return all content which contains a specific keyword. But the response that I get also includes the media files along with the actual content(eg. articles). Is there a filter that I can use to narrow down the search? If not is there a response field upon which I can filter to remove the media files?

```
query search($input:ItemSearchPredicateInput!){
  search(where: $input){
    results{
      id
      name
        path
            version
      url{
        siteName
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query variables:

```
{
  "input": {
      "name":"_name",
      "operator":"CONTAINS",
      "value":"yoga"
  }
}
```

Response

```
//wanted data
{
          "id": "526CFF160B7746FBBF7518922A5A510B",
          "name": "So you want to be a yoga teacher",
          "path": "/sitecore/content/EdgeWebsite/home/sessions/So you want to be a yoga teacher",
          "version": 1,
          "url": {
            "siteName": "edgewebsite"
          }
        }
//unwanted data
        {
          "id": "40AAFB2B8BD540D9808ABF542DD0DEF2",
          "name": "yoga",
          "path": "/sitecore/media library/edgewebsite/data/media/img/categories/yoga",
          "version": 1,
          "url": {
            "siteName": "edge-beta.sitecorecloud.io"
          }
        },
```

Comment: Have you tried using the template Id?

Comment: @RichardSeal Thanks for the suggestion, I am able to filter it using the template id but the main issue with that is that I would need a list of all the template Ids, and the graphql documentation didn't prove to be helpful

Comment: Your template Id's are in Sitecore - just open the CM and you can look them up